# Laravel 5.4 Select Input populate next select input with related data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm making a Laravel 5.4 project where the user should select a school and their class, before they can register. I want them first to select their school in a  element, where the options is populated with schools ofcourse. But how would I get the next  element options populated with the related classes to the school, after they select a school in the first  element?

Comment: *But how would I get the next element options populated with the related classes to the school, after they select a school in the first element* -- you can use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but hope it helps

**View**

```
<select name="school">
      @foreach($allSchools as $school)
         <option value="{{$school->id}}">{{$school->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>

<select name="my_class">
      @foreach($allClasses as $class)
         <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>

<script>
  $("select[name='school']").change(function () {
    var school_id = $("select[name='school']").val();
    if (school_id !== '' && school_id !== null) {
      $("select[name='my_class']").prop('disabled',
      false).find('option[value]').remove();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: {{ url('class/getClass') }}, // do not forget to register your route
        data: {id: school_id },
        }).done(function (data) {
          $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $("select[name='my_class']")
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", key)
                .text(value));
        });
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
          console.log(jqXHR);
      });
   } else {
      $("select[name='my_class']").prop('disabled', 
      true).find("option[value]").remove();
   }
});
</script>
```

**ClassController**

```
public function getClass(Request $request){
  $classes= Class::where('school_id', $request->id)->pluck('name', 'id');
  return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send an AJAX request that gets sent on change event of the school select, then populate the classes with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all the schools and possible classes per every school and store them in an javascript object, then after selecting a school you can refresh the class select box with the corresponding data from the javascript object.

If this data combination is too big to load, you can do an ajax request when selecting a school and retrieve server side the classes for the selected school.